# The trivial problem of weight painting and x symmetry

Tags: weight-painting

I used rigging to build a skeleton, and I turned on x mirror and x symmetry to weight the leg symmetrically.

However, if a weight value is assigned to other bones except for the two bones, the operation will not work.

Is there any way to make this completely symmetrical?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different kinds of symmetry in weight paint:

n. 1 is for "center" bones, where every stroke on the left part of the mesh will be copied on the right side (in the same vertex group).

n. 2 is for couples of bones .L and .R, where a stroke on the .L vertex group will result in a similar mirrored stroke ond the corresponding .R vertex group.

Theese 2 options are not intended to be used together, you have to enable and disable them according to the selected bone/vertex group.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.
However, turning off the x mirror for the central born did not solve the problem.
The weight of the central bone can be fetched from a bone that directly assigns it, but it does not seem to be fetched from a symmetrical bone.